# sum of numbers returns odd low decimals?

Tags: php

When summing a group of numbers sometimes I end up with some low decimals? Why can it happen when the numbers are parsed as strings? I know there is some %"&! about floats

```
function parse(){
    foreach($_SESSION['import_csv_posts']['result']['csv'] as $key => $post){
        $amount = $this->parse_amount($post[$this->param['amount']]);
        if($this->param['vat_amount']){
            $amount += $this->parse_amount($post[$this->param['vat_amount']]);
        }

        $this->balance += $amount;
        echo "$amount\n";
    }

    echo "\nbalance = ".$this->balance;
}

function parse_amount($amount){
    $amount = strval($amount);
    if(strstr($amount, '.') && strstr($amount, ',')){
        preg_match('/^\-?\d+([\.,]{1})/', $amount, $match);
        $amount = str_replace($match[1], '', $amount);
    }

    return str_replace(',', '.', $amount);
}
```

result

```
-87329.00
-257700.00
-11400.00
-9120.00
-47485.00
-15504.00
122800.00
1836.00
1254.00
200.00
360.00
31680.00
361.60
1979.20
1144.00
7520.00
6249.49
balance = -399.00000000003
```

Comment: What are "low decimals"?

Comment: okay, forgive my ignorance, but I don't see where you're parsing the strings to get float value?

Comment: @adnan Happens automatically when using `+=`.

Comment: @deceze or anyone, can someone please explain to me why the result of summing the numbers is different from the output in the question?
http://goo.gl/G8USD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "%"&! about floats" is that floats are simply *not precise*. There's a certain inaccuracy inherent in how infinite numbers are stored in finite space. Therefore, when doing math with floats, you won't get 100% accurate results.

Your choice is to either round, [format numbers](http://php.net/number_format) to two decimal places upon output, or use strings and the [BC Math package](http://php.net/bc), which is slower, but accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point arithmetic is done by the computer in binary, while the results are displayed in decimal. There are many numbers that cannot be represented equally precisely in both systems, therefore there is almost always some difference between what you as a human expect the result to be and what the result actually is when seen as bits (this is the reason that you cannot reliably compare floats for equality).

It does not matter that your numbers are produced through parsing strings, as soon as PHP sees an arithmetic operator it internally converts the strings to numbers.

If you do not *require* absolute precision (which it looks like you do not, as you are simply displaying stuff) then simply use `printf` with a format string such as `%.2f` to limit the number of decimal places.